# Selecting columns/axes for correlation from Pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, correlation

I have a pandas dataframe like the one below. I would like to build a correlation matrix that establishes the relationship between product ownership and the profit/cost/rev for a series of customer records.

```
    prod_owned_a    prod_owned_b    profit      cost    rev
0   1               0               100         75      175
1   0               1               125         100     225
2   1               0               100         75      175
3   1               1               225         175     400
4   0               1               125         100     225
```

Ideally, the matrix will have all prod_owned along one axis with profit/cost/rev along another. I would like to avoid including the correlation between prod_owned_a and prod_owned_b in the correlation matrix.

Question: How can I select specific columns for each axis? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As long as the order of the columns does not change, you can use slicing:

```
df.corr().loc[:'prod_owned_b', 'profit':]
#                profit      cost       rev
#prod_owned_a  0.176090  0.111111  0.147442
#prod_owned_b  0.616316  0.666667  0.638915
```

A more robust solution locates all "prod_*" columns:

```
prod_cols = df.columns.str.match('prod_')
df.corr().loc[prod_cols, ~prod_cols]
#                profit      cost       rev
#prod_owned_a  0.176090  0.111111  0.147442
#prod_owned_b  0.616316  0.666667  0.638915
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very optimized but still;

`df.corr().loc[['prod_owned_a', 'prod_owned_b'], ['profit', 'cost', 'rev']]`

Comment: Perfect, that does exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: @JohnLee If any answer helped, could you please check mark a solution..